# Map with Class as keys and values having objects operating on key class instances

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with Java Generics and I'm not sure if it's even possible what I want to get. Basically title says it all but let me give you an example. Currently I have something like this:

```
private static Map<Class<? extends Exception>, ExceptionTranslator<?>> MAP;
```

which is being used in a following way:

```
MAP.put(SomeException.class, new ExceptionTranslator<SomeException>());
```

But I would like to enforce a translator of the exception type passed as a key, something similar to what you do on methods:

```
<T extends Exception> Map<Class<T>, ExceptionTranslator<T>> MAP;
```

This of course is not a correct code and I guess my generics-foo is not strong enough for this. Is it even possible in Java?

Comment: Why your class doesn't has the `<T extends Exception>` generic in its definition?

Comment: You can't do this with just a normal `Map`; you have to do your own wrapping with a method that enforces the type constraint.

Comment: Thanks, @Louis. "You can't do it" is a valid response and I will accept your answer if you give me the chance. And well, I guess I will need to do what you guys did in Guava:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableClassToInstanceMap.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with just a normal Map; you have to do your own wrapping with a method that enforces the type constraint.  See the related question [Java generics enforce same type for keys and values of map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18156788/869736).

Answer (score 2):

I just want to explain why it is impossible.

The problem is that it is impossible to guarantee type safety. The Map relies on equals/hashMap, which is impossible for compiler to prove correctness of these methods in relation with T type.

Imagine if instead of `Class` you would use your own generic class which will return equals==true for all its instances. In this case you could put into the map one type, but extract with another, it will produce cast exceptions:

```
private<E extends Number> void mp()
{
    Map<Key<E>, E> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(new Key<Integer>(), 42);// Yes, there is compilation error!
    // Otherwise we could do this:
    String str = map.get(new Key<String>());// cast exception!
}

class Key<T>
{
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        return obj instanceof Key;
    }
}
```