# Java generics enforce same type for keys and values of map

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

**What I am looking for:**

I'm looking to construct something that enforces type on both the keys and values of a map: kind of like `Map<Key<X>, Value<X>>`.  However, I would additionally like to enforce that types match *within* each key/value entry, but *between* entries, no type must should be enforced.

For example, within the same map, these key/value pairs should be considered valid:

- `Key<Integer>` maps to `Value<Integer>`
- `Key<String>` maps to `Value<String>`
- `Key<Double>` maps to `Value<Double>`

However, something like this would be invalid:

- `Key<Integer>` mapping to `Value<String>`
- `Key<Double>` mapping to `Value<Boolean>`

How can I accomplish this using Java generics?

---

**What I'm not looking for:**

- I understand that I can implement something like `Set<Pair>`, where
  pair accepts Key/Value of the same type.  However, looking this up by
  key would no longer be a constant time operation.
- I understand that I could do something like `Map<Key<?>, Value<?>>`
  and just assert that the Key and Value are the same type at runtime. 
  However, I was wondering if this is possible strictly using generics.

Comment: Aren't you having that Map inside a generic class?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Just looking to create a `Map` anywhere that just enforces "The keys must be of the same type as the values (or have the same generic type within them, in the case of `Key<X>`/`Value<X>`), but each key/value pair can be of a different type."

Comment: This is exactly what you searched: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter/64694857#64694857

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to roll your own wrapper on top of a `Map`:

```
class MyTypeSafeMap {
  private Map<Key<?>, Value<?>> map;
  public <T> void put(Key<T> key, Value<T> value) {
    map.put(key, value); 
  }

  public <T> Value<T> get(Key<T> key) {
    return (Value) map.get(key); 
    // we know it's safe, but the compiler can't prove it
  }
}
```

Compare e.g. Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MutableClassToInstanceMap.html).

Comment: Does it make any difference whether I cast the return value to (Value) or (Value<T>) ?

Comment: @LucasKuhlemann None whatsoever. Runtime checking of generics bounds isn't possible. Either version doesn't check it (therefore generates a warning), and just assumes you know what you are doing. One via the route of 'oh hey you are using raw types so no type safety', the other via 'oh hey you are casting with generics in the type, which does not do anything, so no type safety'.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***GenericMap*** custom class
and another *generic* class ***GenericKey*** for the key, you can see complete example in this answer

[Java map with values limited by key's type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter/64694857#64694857)