# How to Use Generics in a map of Comparator to avoid warnings

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a map of comparators as following, this map will be used to provide the comparator for each kind of class.

How can I replace the Generic ? in the declaration of my map to be sure that I have always the same Class type in key and value of my map (comparators )?

I want also to reduce the number of warnings

```
 private static final Map<Class<?>, Comparator<?>> comparators = new HashMap<>();

static {
    comparators.put(Identifiable.class, new Comparator<Identifiable>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Identifiable o1, Identifiable o2) {
            return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
        }
    });
    comparators.put(MyClass.class, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(EIntersection o1, EIntersection o2) {
            return o1.getRef().compareTo(o2.getRef());
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use Simple Class without generics? I understand you would get warning from Compiler.. you can use annotation `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` to ignore that warning.

Comment: consider that you can use @SuppressWarning("unchecked") before the method name.

Comment: Why don't you let each class implement Comparator instead?

Comment: @SMA, That is what I did for the moment, but I don't like the @SuppressWarning("unchecked") because it just remove the warning during the compilation, but in reality it still exist. I know also that when I add @SuppressWarning("unchecked") it means that I handled this warning in the code. But I really don't like it. Thanks any way

Comment: @JackFlamp  because my classes are JAXB Beans, so I avoid to modify them as much as I can

Comment: I think you can't get rid of the warning. If you don't want `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` goes everywhere when you use the `Comparator`, you may create a new generic class to enclose everything including the suppresswarning annotation.

Comment: A major strength of java and all Object Oriented languages is that there is a built in ability to avoid Comparators, just by design. So for example (there are much more examples) implement a comperator class with a method that gets two objects of type `MyClass` and so stuff, and overload it with another method that gets two objects of type Identifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce the amount of warnings you can put a wrapper around your comparator map ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156788/java-generics-enforce-same-type-for-keys-and-values-of-map)).

With this solution you have to cast the type only once in your wrapper class (and get only one warning). When calling get on your wrapper class you don't get a warning and don't have to cast the value.

Example:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Comparator<?>> oldComparatorsMap = new HashMap<>();  
private static final Map<Class<?>, Comparator<?>> newComparatorsMap = new MyTypeSafeMap();

static {
    oldComparatorsMap.put(String.class, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    oldComparatorsMap.put(Integer.class, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    newComparatorsMap.put(String.class, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    newComparatorsMap.put(Integer.class, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Comparator<String> c1 = (Comparator<String>)oldComparatorsMap.get(String.class); // Warning for every call on get with a cast

  Comparator<String> c2 = newComparatorsMap.get(String.class); // No warning here and no cast

}

static class MyTypeSafeMap {
  private static final Map<Class<?>, Comparator<?>> innerComparatorsMap = new HashMap<>();

  public <T> void put(Class<T> key, Comparator<T> value) {
    innerComparatorsMap .put(key, value); 
  }

  public <T> Comparator<T> get(Class<T> key) {
    return (Comparator<T>) innerComparatorsMap .get(key); // Only one warning here
    // we know it's safe, but the compiler can't prove it
  }
}
```

Comment: It is better to put the Map inside the class `MyTypeSafeMap` and use the defined method `put` to put the comparators in the static block.

Comment: @Alex The "new" map is inside the class MyTypeSafeMap. I only have the old map  outside to show both cases. But i will rename the variables to make it more clear.

Comment: @BenjaminSchüller MyTypeSafeMap  is better than the old one. Do you have an idea how to add a constraint in the declaration of the map ( Map<Class<?>, Comparator<?>> ) to use the same type ? something like that      Map<Class<T>, Comparator<T>>

Comment: I'm sorry, but i think this is not possible for now.